# Draw over other apps using AccessibilityService

Tags: android, android-activity, service, accessibilityservice

What would be an approach to spawn an activity through a service which overlays on top of all other active applications?

Something akin to how Google Assistant behaves on an "Okay Google" prompt.

I plan on spawning this activity through a gesture so will be catching `AccessibilityEvent`s by creating an `AccessibilityService`. Is that the appropriate method or should I be using a foreground service or the newer `WorkManager`?

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdYNg.jpg)

--
That thing uses accessibility to override draw over apps permission in Android Go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).